# How to add text inside rectangle or circle or any shape using graphiti?

Tags: raphael

If i have made rectangle then it is possible to add any text inside/onto that, like if there is a rectangle and I want to give a name to it for a case RECTANGLE, Something like this :

---

|          |
   |  TEXT    |
   |          |
   |          |

---

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a normal rectangle shape and add a decoration to it. A decoration can be places at any position.

see example: [Figure Locator](http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example/figure_locator)

Greetings

Andreas

Comment: Thanks once again Andreas , I will try this:)